# How can I compare rows of ONE dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, compare, rows, bioinformatics

I have a dataframe with a lot of rows and at least 13 columns. I need to compare each row with the previous one to see if it is exactly the same in two columns and different at the rest.

If two rows are equal in two columns, I would like to put it those rows in a new dataframe.

Here it's my dataframe.

[image]

The first three rows they have the sample "Sample" but only two of them, same "Gene". Rows 7 and 8 have the same sample and gene too.

**I would like to have a NEW DATAFRAME with only the rows that have the same sample and same gene. Like this:**

[image]

I wrote this code:

```
Vec_sample <- c()    
Vec_genes <- c()
Vec_variants <- c()
Vec_chr <- c()
Vec_coordinate <- c()
Vec_aa <- c()
Vec_Rs <- c()
`%notin%` <- Negate(`%in%`)


for (row in 1:nrow(dataframe))
{
  for (row_compare in 1:nrow(dataframe))
  {
    if ((dataframe$Gene[row] == dataframe$Gene[row_compare]) 
        & (row != row_compare))
    {
      if ((dataframe$Sample[row] %notin% Vec_sample) &
          (dataframe$Sample[row] == dataframe$Sample[row_compare]))
      {
        
        Vec_sample <- c(Vec_sample , dataframe$Sample[row])
        Vec_sample <- c(Vec_sample , dataframe$Sample[row_compare])
        Vec_genes <- c(Vec_genes, dataframe$Gene[row])
        Vec_genes <- c(Vec_genes, dataframe$Gene[row_compare])
        Vec_variants <- c(Vec_variants , dataframe$Variants[row])
        Vec_variants <- c(Vec_variants , dataframe$Variants[row_compare])
        Vec_chr <- c(Vec_chr , dataframe$Chr[row])
        Vec_chr <- c(Vec_chr , dataframe$Chr[row_compare])
        Vec_coordinate <- c(Vec_coordinate, dataframe$Coordinate[row])
        Vec_coordinate <- c(Vec_coordinate, dataframe$Coordinate[row_compare])
        Vec_aa <- c(Vec_aa , dataframe$aa[row])
        Vec_aa <- c(Vec_aa , dataframe$aa[row_compare])
        Vec_Rs <- c(Vec_Rs , dataframe$Rs[row])
        Vec_Rs <- c(Vec_Rs , dataframe$Rs[row_compare])
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, when loops are finished, I create a dataframe with the results.

```
final_dataframe <- data.frame(Vec_sample, Vec_genes, Vec_variants, Vec_chr, Vec_coordinate, Vec_aa, Vec_Rs).
```

Everything is duplicated in loops because I need the couple of sample and gene that are equal (and of course, the rest of the information).
I wrote two for loops because I wanted to compare the actual gene with the other.

Problem? If the sample it's already saved in the vector "Vec_sample", if there is another couple with same sample, my script won't saved this couple. (For example, with sample 14-043, firstly it will saved the couple of gene ALG9, but it won't saved the couple of gene MNS1).

Here it's my **wrong new dataframe**.

[image]

I put that exception because when I run the two loops, the table would be check more than once and it would save the gene couple many times and it would be repeated.

Sorry if my syntax or the way of programming is inefficient, I'm starting in this world and I'm not really expert.

I hope I have explained myself well.
Thank you very much in advance

I provide the input data.

```
 structure(list(Sample = c("14-043", "14-043", "14-043", "14-043", 
"14-043", "14-043", "14-077", "14-077", "13-340", "15-642", "15-642", 
"15-642", "12-975"), Gene = c("ALG9", "ALG10B", "ALG9", "SLC5A9", 
"MNS1", "MNS1", "ALG9", "ALG9", "GPI", "MNS1", "HK3", "MNS1", 
"HK3"), Variant = c("T>T/G", "C>A/G", "C>C/G", "A>A/T", "A>T/T", 
"C>C/T", "T>T/G", "C>C/G", "C>G/G", "A>T/T", "T>T/A", "C>C/T", 
"T>T/A"), Chr = c(4, 4, 4, 13, 2, 2, 4, 4, 20, 2, 8, 2, 8), Coordinate = c(23410158, 
3422351, 23410451, 2341043423, 324652341, 3246520, 23410158, 
23410451, 234541, 324652341, 23412341, 3246520, 23412341), aa = c("Gly44Thr", 
"His8Pro", "Ser44Thr", "Thr4Pro", "Ala45Ala", "Ala45Leu", "Gly44Thr", 
"Ser44Thr", "Phe3Ala", "Ala45Ala", "Val34His", "Ala45Leu", "Val34His"
), Rs = c("rs1715919", "rs1734532413", "rs1732413", "rs173240", 
"rs12305", "rs10356", "rs1715919", "rs1732413", "rs12342", "rs12305", 
"rs9997", "rs10356", "rs9997")), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This is definitely not how we do this in R. To compare the rows you would start with something like `head(DF, -1) == tail(DF, -1)`. You do not need loops and you would extract rows using subsetting.

Comment: Please do not provide data as pictures. Provide it as (formated) text in your answer. We can copy data from a picture.

Comment: please can you provide the data as text rather than as an image.  Best to use `dput(dataframe)` to make it easy to import

Comment: Why aren't rows 1 and 2 included? They have the same sample and gene, don't they?

Comment: @Roland  So sorry. I couldn't attach images, only links, because I'm new here.

Comment: @RichardTelford So sorry. I couldn't attach images, only links, because I'm new here

Comment: @Roland but, head (DF, -1) == tail (DF, -1), will check the whole dataframe? I only knew tail and head commands in bash, for get the head and the tail of something, not to compare dataframes.

Comment: @RuiBarradas what image do you mean?

Comment: @Roland I proved compare the rows like this DF[1,] == DF[2,] but I got a warning message like this: Warning message:
In if (het[1, ] == het[2, ]) { :
 the condition has length >1 and only the first element will be used

Why? because it has columns that are equal (TRUE) and columns that they aren't (FALSE).

Comment: It removes the last and first row, respectively, and compares the results.

Comment: You got this warning because you used `if`. You don't need `if`. You are approaching this like a C programmer. R is more high level.

Comment: Please follow the advice by Richard above.

Comment: @Roland well, I don't know nothing about C language. I only know python and R (and I'm very inexpert). I'm doing this in my master thesis in R language, because I thought that it would be more easy, but... I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Yes, provide input data in a usable format as explained above. If you had done that, I'd already have answered this.

Comment: @Roland It is done. I have put it at the end of the post because I couldn't put it here as a comment.
So sorry for everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can do this with `dplyr:filter`, using `lead` and `lag` to check the previous and next rows

```r
df <- structure(list(Sample = c("14-043", "14-043", "14-043", "14-043", 
                          "14-043", "14-077", "14-077", "13-340", "15-642", "15-642", "12-975"
), Gene = c("ALG9", "ALG9", "SLC5A9", "MNS1", "MNS1", "ALG9", 
            "ALG9", "GPI", "MNS1", "MNS1", "HK3"), Variant = c("T>T/G", "C>C/G", 
                                                               "A>A/T", "A>T/T", "C>C/T", "T>T/G", "C>C/G", "C>G/G", "A>T/T", 
                                                               "C>C/T", "T>T/A"), Chr = c(4, 4, 13, 2, 2, 4, 4, 20, 2, 2, 8), 
Coordinate = c(23410158, 23410451, 2341043423, 324652341, 
               3246520, 23410158, 23410451, 234541, 324652341, 3246520, 
               23412341), aa = c("Gly44Thr", "Ser44Thr", "Thr4Pro", "Ala45Ala", 
                                 "Ala45Leu", "Gly44Thr", "Ser44Thr", "Phe3Ala", "Ala45Ala", 
                                 "Ala45Leu", "Val34His"), Rs = c("rs1715919", "rs1732413", 
                                                                 "rs173240", "rs12305", "rs10356", "rs1715919", "rs1732413", 
                                                                 "rs12342", "rs12305", "rs10356", "rs9997")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                            -11L), class = "data.frame")
library(tidyverse)
df %>% filter(Sample == lag(Sample) | Sample == lead(Sample), 
              Gene == lag(Gene) | Gene == lead(Gene))
#>   Sample Gene Variant Chr Coordinate       aa        Rs
#> 1 14-043 ALG9   T>T/G   4   23410158 Gly44Thr rs1715919
#> 2 14-043 ALG9   C>C/G   4   23410451 Ser44Thr rs1732413
#> 3 14-043 MNS1   A>T/T   2  324652341 Ala45Ala   rs12305
#> 4 14-043 MNS1   C>C/T   2    3246520 Ala45Leu   rs10356
#> 5 14-077 ALG9   T>T/G   4   23410158 Gly44Thr rs1715919
#> 6 14-077 ALG9   C>C/G   4   23410451 Ser44Thr rs1732413
#> 7 15-642 MNS1   A>T/T   2  324652341 Ala45Ala   rs12305
#> 8 15-642 MNS1   C>C/T   2    3246520 Ala45Leu   rs10356
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: It works!  But I didn't contemplate in my examples that the genes might not be together... (I wanted to explain it very simple, with a reduced example and I forgot that).

I put the input data again, so sorry for the mistake.

Comment: About my other message, I solved this, ordering by gene and there is no problem now. Thanks you very much!!!